# Is there a way in python to replace a string but leave a middle character intact?

Tags: python

Is there any way to replace all occurrences of a string in a file, while leaving an unknown character in the middle of the string intact?
For example, replacing the string 'ab{unknown}cde' with '(ab{unknown}cde)'

Comment: You should look into regular expressions.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a replacement so much as wrapping a matched substring in parentheses.

```
>>> re.sub('(ab.cde)', r'(\1)', '123abxcde456')
'123(abxcde)456'
```

The pattern is the regular expression `ab.cde`. The parentheses in the pattern indicate that the entire match is a capture group. The replacement text is a pair of parentheses containing whatever the (first) group matched.

Instead of replacement text, you can also specify a function that receives the result of the regular expression match. This lets you, if nothing else, avoid explicitly defining a capture group in the regular expression.

```
def surround(m):
    return f'({m.group()})'

new_str = re.sub('ab.cde', surround, '123abxcde456')
assert new_str == '123(abxcde)456'
```

Comment: suggestion - you could add * or + wildcards to the "." to account for a contingent run of unknown characters if needed

Comment: Yes, you can use any regular expression to match whatever needs to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex that recognizes the known part and replaces the unknown part with some wildcard. in your example,

```
from re import sub

replaced = sub('(ab.cde)', r'(\1)', 'asdasdab5cdeasdasd')
```